# How to keep the ratio between an image and a button when zooming in/out

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a panel that shows an image, a block text and a button, keeping a similar **ratio** to the one shown on the next **mockup** no matter what the page size/zoom is.

[image]

I first tried using an image with the text written across (i.e. not using different sections or divs for text, image and background) but I found it impossible to adapt the **button position** when the text position is changed because of the image expansion/shrinking.

Thus I have thought about separating the essential elements on **different sections** (like in [www.freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com)), one div for the image, one for the background, one for the text and one for the button.

As I am not much experienced with this I wanted to ask for code examples or suggestions about how I could face this challenge in the most efficient way possible, because after researching I didn't find an explanation to a similar situation and I don't even know from where to start.

### Present Code

The **code** I already had (using only one image and the button) is:

**index.html:**

```
<section id="feature_slider">       
        <a class="imagebutton" href="sign-up.html">Start Project Now</a>
</section>
```

**index.css:**

```
#feature_slider {
    margin-top:50px;
    max-width:100% !important;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:contain;
    background: url(../img/backgrounds/BG_whiteb.png) no-repeat;
    height:510px; 
}


.imagebutton
 {
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #FFADEB),
    color-stop(1, #C9498F)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
border-radius:3px;
font-size:32px;
color:#fff;
float:right;
margin-right:12.2%;
margin-top:380px;
padding:15px;
}
```

### Update:

Thanks to @otinanai's examples I managed to make it look more decently, but the problem is that the divs with background images move around when zooming and then the button ends up misplaced. (By the way, I have used an image for the text)
Here is the updated code:

**index.html:**

```
<section id="feature_slider">
    <div id="image1"></div>
    <div id="text1"></div>
    <div id="button1">  <a class="imagebutton" href="sign-up.html">Start Project Now</a> </div>   
    </section>
```

**index.css:**

```
#feature_slider {
    margin-top:50px;
    max-width:100% !important;
   position:relative;
    background:transparent;
    height:510px; 
}

#image1{
        width:70%;
        padding-top:35%;
        margin-top: 58px;
        background:url(../img/red_cut.jpg) no-repeat;
        margin-left: -1%; 
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
}
#text1{width:35%;padding-top:25%;margin-top: 2%;margin-right:2.2%; background:url(../img/text3.png) no-repeat;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;} 

#button1{width:20%;padding-top:5%;background:transparent;position:absolute;right:0;margin-top:23.9%;margin-right:10.5%;}

.imagebutton
 {
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #FFADEB),
    color-stop(1, #C9498F)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFADEB 0%, #C9498F 100%);
border-radius:3px;
font-size:32px;
color:#fff;
padding:7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by using percentage values for the width of each container and with `media queries` you can control various screen sizes.

See a **[simple demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsfJZ/1/)**.

Alternatively, in order to keep aspect ratio, you can utilize `padding-top`, which will be dependent on the size of the container (in %).

**[See this demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UxGXt/2/)** and resize the frame to see how the aspect ratio is kept in all 3 containers.

The only disadvantage to this approach is the use of text or other html elements. Since, I'm using `padding-top` to keep aspect ratio of the container, all children elements will not be aligned to the top of each container. However, you can solve this issue by using `background-images` or by *playing* with negative `margin-top` values OR by just positioning `absolute` all elements within each container [**like this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UxGXt/4/).